# Is there any theorem regarding complement of sets which are subrings/ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with 1.

Let $S$ be any subset of $R$.

Are there any conditions  on $S$ that guarantees that $R\setminus S$ is a subring/ideal?

(Other than the trivial conditions like $S=R\setminus X$ where $X$ is a subring/ideal).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If $S$ is a saturated multiplicative set (that is, $xy\in S$ if and only if $x\in S$ and $y\in S$), then $R\setminus S$ is the union of prime ideals (and conversely). Anyway, since knowing $S$ and $R\setminus S$ is exactly the same, you don't get too much beyond the trivial condition.

Comment: There are two necessary conditions that are easy to check for ideals: $0\notin S$ and if $S\neq \emptyset$ then $1\in S$. For subrings then you  need $0,1\notin S$.